# TEXT() function - where is the documentation?

Tags: c++

I try to find the documentation related to the TEXT()-function in this visual studio cpp tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366551(v=vs.85).aspx

```
TCHAR szName[]=TEXT("Global\\MyFileMappingObject");
```

Unfortunately googling the function leads to results that are not helpful.

Comment: How hard did you try? Do a websearch for TEXT. Well, that gives you lots of hits that are not related. So add something to narrow it down. For example TEXT macro or TEXT MSDN will do the trick. In general if you want to restrict a search to MS docs then just add MSDN to your search term.

Comment: Thanks David. Actually, I did not know how to enrich the search to get better results - next time I will be able to search exclusively on MSDN-website.

Comment: Or go here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/) and search in their box. Strangely this doesn't work as well as straight google search as I described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the MSDN docs on the `TEXT` macro.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374074%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374074%28VS.85%29.aspx)

> **Identifies a string as Unicode when UNICODE is defined by a
>   preprocessor directive during compilation. Otherwise, the macro
>   identifies a string as an ANSI string.**
>
> This macro interprets an ANSI string at runtime according to the
>   current Windows ANSI code page. Literal ANSI strings that are not
>   strictly ASCII are interpreted differently when processed with
>   different Windows ANSI code pages. For example, "\0xC4" in code page
>   1252 (Latin-1) represents Upper Case A with Dieresis (Ä). However, in
>   code page 1253 (Greek), the string represents Upper Case Delta (Δ).
>   These different interpretations lead to development and maintenance
>   issues. For example, a developer might correct a string when using a
>   different system code page from the page used by the original
>   developer; or a build computer might use a different code page. The
>   different interpretations also pose runtime issues, for example, when
>   the end user computer uses a different code page to interpret a string
>   from that used by the build computer.

Found one more link on **[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648008%28VS.85%29.aspx)** where you will find TEXT() function is used.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few links:

- [Data Type Mappings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se784sk6.aspx)
- [Unicode Programming Summary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dybsewaf.aspx)
- [TEXT macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374074%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)